# Updating a taxonomy term, with extra fields - taxonomy_term_update does not exist

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, updating

In Drupal 7, I am trying to update and delete some taxonomy terms in the proper way. So, instead of attacking the database directly, I am using `taxonomy_term_delete` for deleting by **tid**. However I cannot find `taxonomy_term_update` and about `taxonomy_term_save`, it seems not to have access to the extra fields that I added (a few fields, text and integer).

How can I make the following *pseudocode* to work? ( this does not pretend to work, it is just some *pseudocode* in a dialect of Drupal to make the question more understandable )

```
 $term = taxonomy_term_load ( $tid )   // or equivalent function
 $term->extra_field_1 = 23; // extra_field_1 would be numerical
 taxonomy_term_save($term) // o taxonomy_term_update or equivalent
```

Result: the extra_field_1 value of that term ( with tid = $tid ) is set to 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    $terms = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($terms);
    // die();
    //dsm($terms);
    $terms->extra_field_1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0][$column_name] = 23;
    taxonomy_term_save($terms);
```

Use print_r or dsm(devel module if installed) and check the "$column_name".

After print the $terms you able to get "$column_name" replacement. Update that and save.

Comment: Thanks, I was obfuscated and believed that it was not possible, because in the doc there was no reference to the extra fields. Now I saw them as you suggested. May I suggest to use LANGUAGE_NONE instead of "und", it is something I sometimes see in the replies. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes right. You welcome :)